# New Quadkey system for Bing's Birds eye view?

Tags: tiles, bing-maps, quadtree

Has anyone noticed that Bing Maps' Birds eye view seems to be using a new Quadkey system, probably since V8 ? Has anyone been able to convert coordinates to this new system?

The [documentation on Bing's map tile system](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/articles/bing-maps-tile-system) doesn't mention any new Quadkey for bird's eye view.

For example, looking at Notre-Dame in Paris (48.85297, 2.35000) :

- The key for **Aerial view** tile (at zoom level 18) is `120220011012103313` and is consistent with the "old" Quadkey system.
  Link to the tile: http://t.ssl.ak.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a120220011012103313.jpeg?g=11200
- The key for **Birds eye view** view tile is `00030331011233101001` seems to be based on another Quadkey system.
  Link to the tile: https://t.ssl.ak.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/be00030331011233101001?g=11124

For those familiar with the "old" Quadkey system, `00030331011233101001` would point somewhere in the Arctic...

[image]

Before around 2017/2018 and Bing Maps V8, Bird's eye view tiles were using the "old" Quadkey system and I was able to fetch them based on these keys.

Answer (score 1):

Around 2017 Microsoft changed data providers for Birdseye imagery so that likely is the reason for any changes in data format. Note that directly accessing Birdseye tiles outside of the map controls was not allowed by the terms of use previously (I'm assuming it is now since the imagery metadata service now returns the tile URLs which it didn't previously) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/imagery/get-imagery-metadata#get-birdseye-imagery-metadata

Note that Birdsys doesn't use the same quadkey system as base map tiles (it is similar though). The reason for this is that birdseye imagery is scene-based and two scenes can overlap and you can move from one to the other. Birdseye imagery also has scenes from different directions (rotation).